# Python - Is there a way to evaluate a named entity recognizer trained on IOB data using spacy?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, evaluation

I trained my named entity recognizer with spacy. I would like to evaluate it. So I looked at the spacy documentation and came across the scorer function. However, it doesn't seem to work with the IOB format. Do you think there will be a way to use spacy to evaluate my IOB data or am I doomed to transform my data into the format spacy wants?
Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate IOB data directly. You should be able to just use `spacy convert` to convert it to `.spacy` data in one step and then use `spacy evaluate` with that file though. (And if you trained your model in spaCy then presumably you already did the same conversion with your training and dev data?)

Comment: Indeed, I converted my data in .spacy to be able to train my model. So I just need to take my test file and convert it to .spacy? Because in the documentation when they talk about scorer class, they talk about example, a kind of dictionary with data in conll format